# What language is used to create website animations?

Tags: animation

Many websites have loading animations, slide in text and more. What language is used to trigger the animations?

Comment: Typically JavaScript, like everything on the web these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of various technologies can be used, but among the most widespread, there are JavaScript (and many many libraries / technologies built upon it, like jQuery, NodeJS, AngularJS, VueJS, etc.) and HTML5, which includes sets of "native" HTML tags enabling animations (and a lot more than that). Among others, one could also mention Django, which is built in Python.

I hope this helps ; please refer to these technologies' documentations for actual details.

Answer (score 0):

You can, and we used to, animate stuff directly with javascript. This has largely been replaced with css transitions, which are much cleaner. So you define your animation in css with the `transition` rule, and you trigger it with built-in selectors :hover :active :focus etc., or by adding a class to the class list. If you use a js mvvm framework like angular or vue, you can bind your class list to your model. As such, everything is declarative, nothing is procedural. My goodness we've gotten clever :-)